# how to create a list from multiple sublists

Tags: python, list

I have a list with the following structure:

```
list = ['a', ['b','c','d'], ['e','f']]
```

how can I create the following structure from it:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is "flattening" the list. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable name, you're shadowing the builtin class. Sooner or later you'll need to do `list(...)` and end up scratching your head with a `'list' object is not callable` error.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ['a', ['b','c','d'], ['e','f']]
lst = [element for nested_list in list for element in nested_list]
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: This does not generally work, only in this special case because the non-list item happens to be a string (iterable) with only one character. E.g., if the first element was `'xy'` it would give a presumably unexpected result and if it was integers, it would throw an error.

Comment: On a side note, don't use builtin names like `list` as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This supports nested list too.

```
res = []
def parse(li):
    if isinstance(li, list):
        for a in li:
            parse(a)
        return
    res.append(li)
my_List = ['a', ['b','c','d', ['g', 'h']], ['e','f']]
parse(my_List)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'e', 'f']
```